# Reference For the Question Written Below

Tags: reference-request, reference-works

I have had the question below on my term test a few weeks ago; however, I do not know, and I cannot find what textbook this has come from. If could you let me know where that came from, it would be VERY highly appreciated.

**The question is as follows:**

$$\\$$

Assume that the random variable U admits the following compound Poisson representation:

$$U= \sum_{i=1}^{N} B_i$$

Here, the random variable N is Poisson-Distributed with mean $\eta$, and {$B_n, n \geq1$} are independent and identically distributed random variables with common Bernoulli 0/1 distribution with the probability of success $p$, such that $P\{B_i=1\}=p$. Suppose that the random variables {$B_n, n \geq1$} do not depend on the Poisson counting random variable $N$

(i) Find the expectation of the variable $U$

(ii) Find the variance of the random variable $U$

(iii) Compare your results from (i) and (ii). Does it give you a hint on what the distribution of the random variable $U$ can be?

Comment: Not all questions originate from a textbook, otherwise how did they enter the textbook in the first place?

Comment: True, but I'm hoping if there some kind of reference or book that I can use to be ready for questions like this for future term tests